# pyo python module installation failure (Ubuntu 22.10)

Tags: python, python3, 22.10

I am trying to install [pyo][1] on Ubuntu 22.10, and I keep getting this legacy-install-failure error. There doesn't seem to be any documentation that I can find. I have already updated pip, setuptools and wheels. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
         Collecting pyo
      Using cached pyo-1.0.4.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Building wheels for collected packages: pyo
      Building wheel for pyo (setup.py) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1

 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DUSE_PORTAUDIO -DUSE_PORTMIDI -DUSE_OSC -Iinclude -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/engine/ad_portaudio.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/src/engine/ad_portaudio.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-strict-aliasing -O3 -g0 -DNDEBUG
      In file included from src/engine/ad_portaudio.c:21:
      include/ad_portaudio.h:25:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
         25 | #include "portaudio.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyo
  Running setup.py clean for pyo
Failed to build pyo
Installing collected packages: pyo
  Running setup.py install for pyo ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pyo did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [316 lines of output]

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DUSE_PORTAUDIO -DUSE_PORTMIDI -DUSE_OSC -Iinclude -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/engine/ad_portaudio.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/src/engine/ad_portaudio.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-strict-aliasing -O3 -g0 -DNDEBUG
      In file included from src/engine/ad_portaudio.c:21:
      include/ad_portaudio.h:25:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
         25 | #include "portaudio.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyo

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: There is likely an error output somewhere above this message you're specifying issued by the C compiler under the hood.  That is likely VERY important for us to see.  Can you provide the full output, not just the error, for your attempts to install this module with `pip`

Comment: Editing the original post with the full output. I redacted the lines because there were too many. Thanks for your help.